# In SAS Proc SQL what does a "." as a column name mean?

Tags: sas

I'm Converting some Proc Sql statements to t-sql.  I have one that looks like

```
 Proc SQL
 Select 
  ... (extra lines of code here that select normal columns)
 . as NewColumnAlias,
  ... (more lines of code here that select normal columns)
 From $syslast
END
```

What does the "." in the above code mean?  What column does it select?

Comment: A period represents a missing numeric value, roughly equivalent to `NULL as NewColumnAlias`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SAS  a period denotes a [numeric missing value](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p0ueqauvtyb2hqn1mj79t26azlxv.htm). This essentially sets your column to missing everywhere.

[image]